# java ReentrantLock tryLock() misunderstanding

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

```
    ReentrantLock l = new ReentrantLock(true);
            Reader[] readers = new Reader[2];
    
            for (int i = 0; i < readers.length; i++) {
                readers[i] = new Reader(l);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < readers.length; i++) {
                readers[i].start();
            }

public class Reader extends Thread {

    private ReentrantLock l;

    public Reader(ReentrantLock l) {
        this.l = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
              l.tryLock();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " i =  " + i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
//            l.unlock(); // although it commented the code not hanged why?
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

according to my understanding to tryLock() Acquires the lock if it is not held by another thread and returns immediately now in my case i have two threads suppose thread_0 get lock now i have two questions :
Q1: why thread_1 still enter the critical section after l.tryLock() isn't it locked by thread_0;
Q2: isn't it supposes to my code to be hanged because thread_0 doesn't release the lock
#thanks advance

Comment: You have to check the return value. If `tryLock()` returns false, you didn't acquire the lock.

Comment: @shmosel suppose i don't checke and thread_0 come and execute  l.tryLock() and it  return true then why thread_1 still access my critical section isn't my critical section locked by thread_0 as  l.tryLock(); return true

Comment: @ahmedahmed If your code enters a section without ensuring it holds the lock first, then by definition that section is *not* a critical section. So you don't actually have a critical section because a thread can enter the section without holding the lock if `tryLock` fails.

Comment: If `tryLock()` blocked until the lock was free it would be no different than `lock()`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz isn't l.tryLock(); if it return true == l.lock();

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how locks work. Calling `lock()` doesn't inherently block other threads from accessing a block of code. It just forces other threads calling `lock()` to wait until you `unlock()`. If one thread locks over a block of code, nothing prevents another thread from accessing the same code without acquiring the same lock. If you call `tryLock()` and it returns false, your thread doesn't have the lock and it's on you to ensure the critical section is not executed.

Comment: @ahmedahmed But your code enters the following section even if `tryLock` returns `false`. Since a thread can enter that section without holding the lock, that section is *not* a critical section.

Comment: @ahmedahmed Why do you think the code would hang? What function would the code hang on? There is no critical section in this code for the reason that I explained.

Comment: @David Schwartz thank you very much for your help  but I was think for example if 
thread_0 called l.tryLock(); and it return true then it behaves like l.lock()
but I understand that when we call l.lock(); one thread get the lock and others wait until they get  the lock
BUT we call l.tryLock() i must make sure the thread get the lock as the others will not wait

Comment: @ahmedahmed I'm not really sure I understand what you're saying. But you seem to think this code will hang. What function do you think will hang? The `tryLock` function never hangs.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is entering the critical section because, tryLock() is not a blocking function, it will return true or false immediately, and proceed with the "Critical Section" code snippet below.

In the documentation of tryLock() you can read

> If the lock is held by another thread then this method will return
> immediately with the value false.

So you need to call lock() method, which waits until the lock is released by another reader.